# Create apk file for iOS, Android, Blackberry etc

Tags: ios, file, apk

I have create a sample mobile application but I don't know how to create apk file for all platform like `Android`, `iOS`, `Blackberry`, `Windows` phone. How can I create apk file for all these platform. I am using windows operating system, so please suggest me that how can I create `.apk` file for all mobile device from windows system.

Comment: Bro..which platform u r using?? Apk only work for android. For other u need different files. for ex. for iOS we need .ipa

Comment: I am unable to do this task

Answer (score 0):

First of all APK is an installation file for the android OS. You can't install this file in an other devices. There is a possibility that you may can crack the android app in a blackberry device.

http://crackberry.com/how-install-android-app-apk-blackberry

Otherwise you have to create single app for each OS. Their installation file may be different(IPA for IOS,..).

If you are looking for cross platform mobile application(working in multiple platforms), there is a nice tutorial [here](http://coronalabs.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started-with-corona/)

Comment: svrushal currently I am using android working on eclipse, I want to create installation file for all platform. I am new in mobile application so I don't know the file extension, please help.

Comment: @amit you cant create an installation file for all platform

Comment: Yes svrushal I know I can create installation file but how?